# Erro para deixar aplicação com a autenticação pelo Windows

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, autenticação, wcf

Estou tentando deixar uma aplicação com a  autenticação pelo Windows. 
Porém quando altero as configurações no IIS  com a autenticação anônima desabilitada conforme a imagem abaixo:
[image]
Tenho o seguinte erro:

> [MessageSecurityException: A solicitação HTTP não está autorizada no esquema de autenticação de cliente 'Anonymous'. O cabeçalho de autenticação recebido do servidor foi 'Negotiate,NTLM'.]

Estou usando um WCF, já fiz várias alterações no webconfig porém sempre volta para esse erro.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Answer (score 0):

Adicione este trecho ao `web.config`. Se você vai usar autenticação do Windows, não é necessário ter a **personificação do ASP.NET** ativa

```xml
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Desativei personificação do ASP.NET, e acrescentei esse código no web.config, mas continuo com o mesmo erro.

Comment: @lucas Você conseguir resolver? Eu tenho palpite pra este problema. Se precisar ainda, vou precisar confirmar algumas coisas com você

Comment: Ainda não consegui resolver.

Comment: Se você clicar com o botão direito em "Windows Authentication" e depois em **providers**, o que aparece?